# rspec rails 3.2.3, and ruby 1.9.3 getting cannot load such file errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec2

When I run:

`bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`:

I get:

```
c:\Sites\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/conf
iguration.rb:746:in `load': cannot load such file -- c:/Sites/spec/requests/stat
ic_pages_spec.rb (LoadError)
    from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
    from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
    from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

I'm getting a similar error to the one contained in this post, however the solution proposed doesn't work for me.

[spec with guard, rails 3.1.1, and ruby 1.9.3 getting cannot load such file errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024031/spec-with-guard-rails-3-1-1-and-ruby-1-9-3-getting-cannot-load-such-file-error)

I've run `bundle install` and `rails generate rspec:install` but the error remains. All the files are in their correct spots, and nothing has changed since last night, so I'm not sure what has happened.

Any light shed on the situation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like rspec does not care that you stand in c:\sites\sample_app, as it tries to load

```
c:/Sites/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

Try to run rspec with an absolute path:

```
 bundle exec rspec c:/Sites/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

Comment: That's it, you're a legend. It would have happened because earlier today I jumped into regedit to add an autorun for the command prompt to start me in c:\Sites rather than having to navigate to it every time I opened the command prompt. I didn't know it would affect this. I undid it and it worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: The 'bundle exec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb' command must be run from the sample_app folder. I was trying to run it in deeper directories and it didn't work til I want back up to sample_app.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are executing the `bundle exec rspec spec/....` command from the app root directory.  If you run the command from a sub-directory, you will get this error.